# The CSS style of my Jekyll template is not working

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I used a Jekyll template to create a website. Now I published the site online (webgov.be) an the CSS is not as it was supposed to be. This is the link to the repo: https://github.com/evelinevlas/webgov. On GitHub Pages the website was published with the right CSS and layout but on my own custom domain it was not..

Does anyone know what the reason is why the website is not published well?
Does it has something to do with my domain?

This is how the website is showing up at the moment:
[wrong displaying of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1uNX.png)

And this is how it was build (and how it showed up on GitHub-pages), how I would like it to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWA0e.png)

Answer (score 1):

As your problem was fixed by changed `baseurl` and no longer reproductible, you can delete your question.